# Filesystem that removes everything when getting full

Tags: mount, kernel, tmpfs

I'm wondering if there is a solution that enables me to drop a filesystem that becomes full.

Why such a weird idea?

I have a thumbnailer called tumbler. It generates thumbnails of pictures I browse with filemanager called Thunar. It generates lots of them, filling up space and killing SSD, so I moved thumbnails directory to tmpfs filesystem with size=400M.

This solves the issue of filling disk space (reboot will clear tmpfs which is located in RAM) and improves SSD life.

However, when the limit is reached, no more thumbnails are being generated and other programs relying on tumbler tend to freeze.

Yes, I know this could be solved by a cron script checking directory size every minute and removing files but I'm just wondering if there's more elegant solution.

//edit: yeah, it should be all configurable from Tumbler (it's not from what I know) but this 400MB can be filled in few minutes and I don't have more RAM to spend on this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "drop a filesystem"?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your "tumbler" program. It seems more reasonable to have it check its own usage and start removing older files when it needs to write new ones. Is that an option?

Comment: @terdon I checked that before asking the question, there seems to be no way.

Comment: @L.Ray I was referring to database vocabulary. DB drop means that all data gets removed. The thing is that I'm not sure what should be the solution (some filesystem? nfs? some pseudo-device? mount option?), so I'm trying to use mix of expressions, so the question won't be associated with any particular solution.

Comment: I remember some exe thumbnailer which had a setting for max thumbnails, but i can't remember seeing any deletion-routine. Since all names a unique, you can't go with overwriting. Didn't tmpfs delete older content, when you write too much? There is no fs that will delete files itself.

Comment: Consider configuring logrotate to remove and/or archive files from the directory in question.  Let me know if you need more explaination.

Comment: @L.Ray from what I know it's impossible to run logrotate more often than daily without creating a cron job :) So if I create a cron job, then I may as well write a custom script instead of using logrotate.

Comment: @WGRM tmpfs doesn't have such functionality from what I know and man page tells me. I need to use tumbler for xfce environment unfortunately.